# How to present a large dataset consisting of species population count over a 40 year period in a readable graph format

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I created a pivot table and chart, detailing the different species and their population over a 40-year period, this is split up into seasons for each year. I would like to know if there is a better way of presenting the dataset, as it is difficult to visually analyze and create a hypothesis from the pivot cluster bar chart that was created.

I've attached images of what the dataset looks like and what charts I've produced using excel, I would like to stick to excel as I don't have the time to learn programs such as R.

Pivot table with the top row being the species name and the numbers being the count.
[image: Pivot table with the top row being the species name and the numbers being the count.]

Pivot chart with seasons on the bottom and the colours representing the different species
[image: Pivot chart with seasons on the bottom and the colours representing the different species]

Line graph works, but still hard to spot long-term and short-term patterns, as I have a lot of species I don't want to do a separate line graph for all of them:
[image: Line graph]

Thank you

Comment: How about a line graph for each species over time.

Comment: I've attached an image of the line graph, still hard to spot patterns.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's primary not an Excel question. Making a meaningful visualization requires aggregation of the data. We can't help with that as we don't know the data.

Comment: I would suggest making the graph wider than the visible area.  Yes, you will have to scroll left and right but things will be less crowded.  Maybe 4 or 5 times the width of your screen.  Otherwise can do 10 lines per graph maybe?  How many species do you have?

Comment: I think excel also has an option for stacked line graphs.

Comment: This is likely too much information for a single chart. Also, improving it is a function of your intent and your audience and opinion.